# How can I detect which custom button was tapped in a bank of custom buttons in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a bank of 6 custom buttons which I implemented using images with user interaction enabled. I also added a tag to each switch. I attached a tap gesture recognizer to each button. I used a techniques described in
[detect view was tapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641669/how-can-i-figure-out-which-view-was-tapped-on-in-ios) 
When I press any of the buttons I always get the last button that the gesture was attached to. Here is the code. Help would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var buttonImages: [UIImageView]!

var selectedOption = 0

@IBAction func tapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let buttonImage = sender.view!
    println("Tag: \(buttonImage.tag) image: \(buttonImage)")
    selectedOption = (sender.view?.tag)!
    println("tapped: \(selectedOption)")
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
        action: "tapped:")
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    let x = UIImage(named:"TV normal.png") // replace with array

    var tag = 0
    for buttonImage in buttonImages {
        buttonImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        buttonImage.image = x
        buttonImage.tag = tag
        tag++
    }
    // check
    for buttonImage in buttonImages {
        println("Tag: \(buttonImage.tag) image: \(buttonImage)")
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is due to the fact you are attaching the same `UITapGestureRecognizer` for each `UIImage`, but a gesture can be attached to only one `UIView` at the same time, that's why you always getting back the last one.

In your case, you just need to create a new `UITapGestureRecognizer` for each `UIImage` you are creating with the same target / action. This way, your method `tapped` will work.